# Split BigInteger into digits and put them in an array

Tags: java, biginteger

I want split the following biginteger into digits and put it in an array.

```
BigInteger = 123456789123456789123456789123456789
array[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,}
```

How can I do this?Thank you.I searched it but couldn't find a better answer.

Answer (score 5):

Could do it as follows:

```
BigInteger value = new BigInteger("123456789123456789123456789123456789");
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
BigInteger ten = new BigInteger("10");
while (!value.equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
{
    list.add(0, value.mod(ten).intValue());
    value = value.divide(ten);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do `toString` and turn each character to `int` and add to array of `int`s

```
String biStr = bi.toString();
int[] ints = new int[biStr.length()];
for(int i=0; i<biStr.length(); i++) {
    ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(biStr.charAt(i)))
}
```